# ImportError: No module named osv

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-xp, odoo, openerp-7

Hi I have been developing an openerp 7 module in python. I am using `eclipse` and I installed the all-in-one `openerp-7` in my windows XP.

Now when I import osv file like:

```
from osv import fields
```

I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named osv

I checked my osv file which is in my openerp folder created during installation.

#### Question

How could I be able to resolve it.

Comment: in python console can you do `import osv` ?

Comment: since I am using eclipse , and I am importing osv so as to add field to my openerp module

Comment: You have to make sure that the module is placed correctly in the addons folder.

Comment: I have placed it there . It is available in openerp modules but on installing it gives error . That might be because of " osv file "

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this

```
from openerp.osv import fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the error from Eclipse or from the Python console?

If it is from your Eclipse, what happens if you ignore it and install your module in OpenERP?

Comment: how do I know if my module is installed or not ? Its status is installed but under which app can I find it?

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani Can you start OpenERP? If so you could login as admin and go to "Settings" -> "Update Modules List", then go to "Installed Modules" and tick off the "Installed" filter, search for the name of your module (the folder name of your module).

Comment: sir you are not getting me . I know that its under that list but how could we find out the exact form of a module after its being installed

Comment: I'm still not getting you. If the status of your module in OpenERP is "Installed", it means your module has been installed. I wanted to know when the osv import error has occurred.

Comment: my module has been installed because its status is installed but I cant set my fields and menus to give my module more meaning . I am creating .py file of my module . The first line of code is "form openerp.osv import osv,fields" , bu doing this I will be able to define the fields but I am getting an error that " no  module named openerp.osv" found . I am compiling on eclipse.

Comment: Then it is an Eclipse (PyDev plugin) configuration problem, there is nothing wrong with the import code. Google how to add python libs to Eclipse's python libs path.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu18, odoo13, Postgres 12.

this is similer too ?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ir' from 'odoo.addons.base'
```

odoo13

```
lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo.osv.orm'
```

**this work for me**

```
import odoo.osv
import odoo
from odoo.osv import orm
```

Comment: import odoo.osv
import odoo
from odoo.osv import orm

Answer (score 0):

please check this one from this change just openerp to odoo name change you need to change in your code

for odoo 9 version or previous

```
from openerp.osv import fields
```

after odoo 9 v3ersion

```
from odoo.osv import fields
```